# Is this ODE solvable by Cauchy-Euler?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Q1]

$$ y' = \lambda \times x^{\lambda - 1} $$
$$ y'' = (\lambda - 1 )\times \lambda \times x^{\lambda - 2} $$

since $ y(x) =  x^{\lambda} $

I put it into action and using simple expanding, bla bla bla and I come to this dead end:

$$ x^{\lambda} [ (\lambda^2 - \lambda) x^2 + 4 (\lambda^2 - \lambda) x + 4 (\lambda^2 - \lambda) - x^2] = 0$$

As I recall, I was supposed to left the equation with only  $ {\lambda} $ and coefficients so I can solve the roots of the $ {\lambda} $. But in here, I stuck with another Diff. Equation. And I don't think my teacher gave me a false question. So, can you see where I am doing wrong? I did the calculation like 5 times!

Comment: Please take the time to type out the MathJax of the question.

Comment: @SimpleArt apologize, this is the final Q. I removed the wrong equality.

Comment: Hint $y(x) = (x+2)^{\lambda}$ is of the stated form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $u=x+2$, then $dy/dx=du/du$, and you can do the second derivative.  Then you have the Cauchy-Euler form.